# Change offset of a Point without moving line border

Tags: chart.js

Couldn't find how to move Point, which i changed to triangle so it looks like arrow. I need it to be aligned to the left side of the border.

[image]

Here what i have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/zeuv7bj6/17/

```
const data = {
                      labels: chartLabels,
                      datasets: [{
                          data: chartData,
                          borderWidth: 2,
                          fill: true,
                          borderColor: ["#03A9F5"],
                          backgroundColor: '#4985ff45',
                          pointStyle: 'triangle',
                          pointBackgroundColor: "#03A9F5",
                          pointRadius: 7,
                          // pointOffsetX: -5 Would be great to have, but unfortunately...
                          hoverRadius: 10,
                          rotation: 90,
                        }
                      ]
                    };
```